# Dragging and dropping a file from the file system with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver

i am testing a Web-Application, One of the scenario is the ability to drag a file from the file system and drop it onto the component.

similar to this :

http://s3u.github.com/har-view/

http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

Is there a way to simulate dropping a file from the file system onto
an element using web driver?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, `WebDriver` only drives the browser and can't touch anything outside of it. If you want to drag'n'drop something in, you'll have to use [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) or any other tool ([there might be a library for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java%20drag%27n%27drop%20programmatically)).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me was running a JS code that i found in [Selenium: Drag and Drop from file system to webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829153/selenium-drag-and-drop-from-file-system-to-webdriver)

Just copy paste the whole thing in to your project.

See:
 static void DropFile(IWebElement target, string filePath, int offsetX = 0, int offsetY = 0)
        {

```
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
        }



        IWebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)target).WrappedDriver;
        IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));


        string JS_DROP_FILE = @"
    var target = arguments[0],
        offsetX = arguments[1],
        offsetY = arguments[2],
        document = target.ownerDocument || document,
        window = document.defaultView || window;

    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.style.display = 'none';
    input.onchange = function () {
      target.scrollIntoView(true);

      var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
          x = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width >> 1)),
          y = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height >> 1)),
          dataTransfer = { files: this.files };

      ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'drop'].forEach(function (name) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
        evt.initMouseEvent(name, !0, !0, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null);
        evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer;
        target.dispatchEvent(evt);
      });

      setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(input); }, 25);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    return input;
    ";

        IWebElement input = (IWebElement)jse.ExecuteScript(JS_DROP_FILE, target, offsetX, offsetY);
        input.SendKeys(filePath);
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(input));
```

Comment: Can you add more content to your post? IF the link you provided changes, your answer won't help anymore.