# how to drag and drop external image into browser using java-Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

I want to write a test case for drag and drop functionality using Selenium & Java.

I want to drag image from dynamic folder from main folder into web browser.

```
waitForElement(driver, By.xpath(".//*[@href='/stock/create?productType=1']"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@href='/stock/create?productType=1']")).click();
    waitForElement(driver, By.className("jFiler-input-dragDrop"));
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("D:/StockarsRegression/stockarsregressionsuite/Images/Ashok Leyland")); 
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.className("jFiler-input-dragDrop"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Please find the above code:

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: You cannot do that with Selenium (Windows folder to Web). You can only drag and drop elements within the browser.

Comment: But you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829153/selenium-drag-and-drop-from-file-system-to-webdriver/38830823#38830823