# Drag and Drop local File in browser with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how can I drag and drop local file with selenium C#? It is possible?

Comment: You could accomplish this with AutoIT. Selenium does not interact with windows objects. https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/122881-files-drag-drop/

Comment: is there a browse button from which you can select the directory and select that file?

Comment: Selenium to my knowledge is to perform interactions on your browser alone so you will not be able to perform desktop environment interactions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: Drag and Drop from file system to webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829153/selenium-drag-and-drop-from-file-system-to-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in Selenium with C# for web element.you can use below code

```
Action.ClickAndHold(onElement);    

Action.MoveToElement(toElement);  

Action.Release(toElement);   

Action.Build().Perform();
```