# Check Drag and Drop Functionality of a Web Application

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to implement a tool that checks whether a website has a drag and drop file upload functionality. Specifically, if a website such as [this](https://code-boxx.com/simple-drag-and-drop-file-upload/) has a drag and drop file upload functionality, my tool needs to return True.

I found this code this Python [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829153/selenium-drag-and-drop-from-file-system-to-webdriver?rq=1) which utilizes Selenium to upload a file from the local file system to a website with drag and drop. It needs an `element_id` of the drag/drop area and the path of the file.

I updated this code to build my tool. Specifically, my code first retrieves all of the elements of the website and checks whether the file is droppable returns `True`. However, it still returns True even though the some 'ids' given to the functions are not droppable. I want to get return True only if the given "id" uploads to the file to the webserver.

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
for ii in ids:
    all_ids.append(ii.get_attribute('id'))
    #print(ii.get_attribute('id'))    # id name as string
    try:
        dropzone = driver.find_element_by_id(ii.get_attribute('id'))
        dropzone.drop_files("/Users/pythonSelenium/test.png")
        return True

    except: 
        continue
```

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean value which is set to true only if the element is dropped, otherwise returning false.

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
for ii in ids:
    all_ids.append(ii.get_attribute('id'))
    #print(ii.get_attribute('id'))    # id name as string
    dropped = False
    try:
        dropzone = driver.find_element_by_id(ii.get_attribute('id'))
        dropzone.drop_files("/Users/pythonSelenium/test.png")
        dropped = True
    except: 
        continue
return dropped
```